# The Ruby way to do fail on database save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby and Ror so any guidance would be awesome. I have a function:

```
def self.insert_feed_product_scores(id, low, high)
  avgScore = low.to_s + " - " + high.to_s
  @feedProduct = FeedProduct.find(id)
  @feedProduct.avg_score = avgScore
  @feedProduct.save
end
```

If for some reason the id that I pass in isn't found, I notice I get this error, thats fine:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find FeedProduct with id=999999
```

I could write some logic and check if there is a score and there is something found before I save, but it just doesn't seem like the Ruby way of doing things...should I just write in logic to validate or is there some Ruby/Ror way of doing things?

Thanks

Comment: try?http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try

Comment: is this a classmethod of FeedProduct? do you say is it ok to raise an exception? then using find is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to track the error message and log properly, follow @lucapette answer. Else

```
def self.insert_feed_product_scores(id, low, high)
  @feedProduct = FeedProduct.find(id) rescue return false
  @feedProduct.avg_score = "#{low} - #{high}"
  @feedProduct.save
end
```

Comment: better: `@feedProduct = FeedProduct.find_by_id(id) or return false`

Comment: @tokland, using `or` won't catch the exception, hence the code will break there.

Comment: find_by_id does not raise exceptions.

Comment: Oops... Sorry, I haven't paid enough attention. My mistake :)

Comment: cool, this looks to me like the best answer. Thanks for you help guys.

Answer (score 2):

```
def self.insert_feed_product_scores(id, low, high)
  avgScore = low.to_s + " - " + high.to_s
  begin
    @feedProduct = FeedProduct.find(id)
    @feedProduct.avg_score = avgScore
    @feedProduct.save
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    logger.info("Record not found: ", id)
  end
end
```

It's a way of doing it. But different ways handling this kind of situations is a matter of taste IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this in such situations:

```
@feedProduct = FeedProduct.where(id: id).first
if @feedProduct
  @feedProduct.avg_score = avgScore
  @feedProduct.save
end
```

That'll safely save a product.

Answer (score 0):

It's not idiomatic to send *ids* to a class-method, I'd add a method to `FeedProduct` instead:

```
class FeedProduct
  ...
  def set_scores(low, high)
    self.update_attribute(:avg_score, "#{low}-#{high}")
  end
  ...
end
```

To be used this way:

```
FeedProduct.find(feed_product_id).set_scores(1, 10)
```